# Evenly divisible ceiling number

Tags: c#, math, decimal

I need some help with some simple math calculation and the most efficient way to execute them in c#.

```
10 / 4 = 2.5
```

How do i determine if the sum is a decimal value and if it is I need to round 4 up to 5 so that it divides into 10 evenly.

Any ideas?

Comment: You will only get a `2` with that calculation, as this is integer division.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that, given some numbers A and B, you want to find a number x, such that:

- x evenly divides A
- x is greater than or equal to B
- x is minimized

in your given example, A = 10, B = 4, and x = 5.
The simplest-to-code way to find x is:

```
public int getX(int a, int b){
    while(a % b != 0){
        b++;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Generally speaking, it's not easy to find factors of an arbitrary number. In fact, some computer fields, such as cryptography, depend on the fact that factoring big numbers takes a long time.

Comment: Assuming you don't know there is a solution, you need error handling - so some kind of fail value or exception is needed. E.g. `A = 11, B = 4`. Also, factors occur in pairs, at least one of which is `<= sqrt(A).`; with some care you can reduce the search space, but note that it might be that `sqrt(A) > B > x1`, and `x = A/x1` so we can't simply terminate when `b > sqrt(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds extremely vague. You could figure it out using

```
if (10%4 != 0) ... //checks if there is a remainder
```

But how to get it up to 5 would need a lot more context.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion for a short function doing that:

```
private int FindCeilingDevider(int numberToDivide, int divisor)
{
    double result;

    do
    {
        result = (double) numberToDivide / (double) divisor;
        divisor++;
    }
    while (result != Math.Ceiling(result));
    return divisor - 1;
}
```